# Will this cause a race condition?

Tags: multithreading

I made a program in C that will create 10 threads, and inside each thread add 10,000 integers [0-100]. When the thread ends it adds the partial sum to the total sum. It is unlikely that 2 threads will end at the exact same time, but if they do will there be a problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include<pthread.h>

pthread_t pid[10];
int i = 0;
int sum;

void* partial(void *arg)
{
    int partial = 0;
    pthread_t id = pthread_self();

    int k = 0;
    for(k = 0; k < 10000; k++) {
        int r = rand() % 101;
        partial += r;
    }
    sum += partial;
    return NULL;
}

main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    clock_t begin,end;
    double timeSpent;
    begin = clock();

    while(i < 10) {
        pthread_create(&(pid[i]), NULL, &partial, NULL);
        printf("\n Thread created successfully\n");
        i++;
    }

    sleep(10);
    end = clock();
    timeSpent = (double)(end-begin);
    printf("\n Time taken: %f", timeSpent);
    printf("\n sum: %d \n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes. `a += b` is compiled as `temp x = a; x = x + b; a = x`. If two threads execute that code at the same time there is a chance that both will read the same original value of `a`, both will add their value to it and then write it back into `a`, but only the last one to execute will win. You might loose updates. Also, why didn't you tag this `C`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, without locking with mutexes there is (an unlikely but possible) chance of a race condition. 
If two threads do finish at the same time they will try to modify the common resource (`sum`) at the same time and that will lead to the common resource not being updated properly, since both threads will "race" to read the value of `sum` when incrementing it in the statement `sum+=partial`.